# Is there a way to use the nmea_gps_driver on electric version of ros?

Tags: gps, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the documentation, they say i can only use this driver in fuerte version or newer, due to the dependency on sensor_msgs/TimeReference

Is it possible to chance the driver so it doenst have this depency, or to chance ros electric to have this depency?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30794/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-nmea_gps_driver-on-electric-version-of-ros?/) by [BetoCC011](https://answers.ros.org/users/2041/betocc011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From a [glance at the code](https://kforge.ros.org/gpsdrivers/nmea_gps_driver?p=nmea_gps_driver;a=blob;f=src/nmea_gps_driver.py;h=4c796de2855dcc9c4aaeab785315c26dc6994a60;hb=HEAD), it certainly looks possible.

If you have time to work on it, check out the git sources and make a patch to submit. A single solution that works with both Electric and Fuerte would be ideal.

UPDATE: I've given some thought to how this could be done in Python. First make the import conditional:

```
try:
    from sensor_msgs.msg import TimeReference
except ImportError:
    TimeReference = None
```

Then, make sure `TimeReference` is `True` before doing anything with the `gpstime` variables:

```
if TimeReference:
    gpstimePub = rospy.Publisher('time_reference', TimeReference)
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would certainly be possible to remove that dependency, as long as, as @joq mentions, it's a single solution that keeps the functionality for Fuerte and provides compatibility with Electric.

Please file an enhancement ticket for this functionality on the [project trac](https://kforge.ros.org/gpsdrivers/trac/newticket?component=nmea_gps_driver&type=enhancement&nmea_gps_driver) (note you can also find that link at the bottom of [nmea_gps_driver](http://ros.org/wiki/nmea_gps_driver) under "Request features") and reply here with the link once you've done that.

If you want to go ahead and create a patch that provides Electric compatibility, just attach it to that ticket and I'll gladly take a look at it.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2